# Dreamweaver CS6 Character Issue

Tags: php, character, dreamweaver

I open new PHP Page in dreamweaver and typing my codes. Saving as php file and upload my ftp. And then when try to open that page i got error something like that;

> ��\IsG�>��%x!��n�(.���d)D�94��]J��]�$A����4a}�.sҍ��z_VU/
>   @��/��@-�YYY�U�w��|������~�ܦ�Lz���ѷk����SK�z��н�
>   �ч�v)7�q�m"���u�c&O:�$B�����Nm���œ �m6OOO

But when type exactly the same code in windows text editor and saving as php file and upload my ftp. It working fine , no crazy error like dreamweaver's file..

what could cause this ? how can i fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a character encoding issue.  Have a look at [this](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/dreamweaver/mx2004/dwusing_errata/dwusing_errata2.html).